# Is it possible to get rid of the so-called 'Spurious Tuples' completely?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

Is it possible to get rid of the so-called 'Spurious Tuples' completely?

For example: in [this example](https://books.google.pl/books?id=DEFsCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=what%20is%20spurious%20tuple&source=bl&ots=G4ER0YMCyr&sig=XUGUwAYKRXOwBQ2w7y4sCtdiink&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20spurious%20tuple&f=true), I don't see anything wrong with the base-tables.

But, it is still generating spurious tuples after joining.

Comment: I have answered this exact question over on [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121519/is-it-possible-to-get-rid-of-the-so-called-spurious-tuples-completely)

Answer (score 1):

In the decomposition of a relational schema a "spurious tuple" is just a hypothetical symptom of lost information. What it means is that some dependency represented in a given relation will be lost as a result of splitting that relation into two or more components. Whether that's a problem you need to solve or not depends on how important the lost dependency is to you.

In the example you refer to, the EmpRoleProj table tells us what projects each employee is working on. In the Table1, Table2 design that information is lost - we can no longer tell that Jones works only on the Amazon project and not on the Nile project.

As a database designer you need to consider what information or integrity has been lost and then decide what action to take: change the design, add extra integrity constraints or decide that the new decomposition is actually an improvement on what went before it.

Answer (score 0):

If relation R equals R1 JOIN R2 JOIN ... then we can use R1 JOIN R2 JOIN ... instead of R. Obviously. But R1, R2, ... will be projections of R. Whereas if we take projections R1', R2', ... of R where R does *not* equal R1' JOIN R2' JOIN ... then we *can't* use R1' JOIN R2' JOIN ... instead of using R. Obviously. But R1' JOIN R2' JOIN ... will be like R *plus some other tuples*. They are "spurious tuples" compared to the value of R and R1 JOIN R2 JOIN ... . But they *belong* in R1' JOIN R2' JOIN ... . *That just isn't R*. To "get rid of the spurious tuples" *just don't use R1' JOIN R2' JOIN ... for R*. But then, why *would* you? Only if you thought that any old projections of R JOIN back to R. But they don't. But then, why *would* they?

So your question is oddly phrased. We want to replace a table that is the join of some others by those others. We *don't* want to replace a table that is *not* the join of some others by those others. So we can *always* "get rid of the spurious tuples" by *not doing that*.

Normalization is about replacing a table that is the join of some others by those others. When R = R1 JOIN R2 JOIN ... we say that a JD (join dependency) holds in R. Contrary to received wisdom, it's *very easy* to see JDs if we are looking and we know what our tables mean. When R holds tuples where "*...A1a...A1b...* AND *...A2a...A2b...* AND ...", it is the join of R1, R2, ... on respective attribute sets {A1a, A1b, ...}, {A2a, A2b, ...}, ... with respective meanings "*...A1a...A1b...*", "*...A2a...A2b...*", ... . We *naturally* use R1, R2, ... *most of the time* from *the start of design*. Received wisdom is also that JDs not accompanying FDs (functional dependencies) are rare. They are, but only because *most JDs are so obvious that our initial designs avoid them*. They are "hard to find" only because they are so easy to find. (It is a bit more complicated to not decompose per JDs that don't cause problems.)